# libspotify - There was an error generating your application key

Tags: spotify, libspotify

It appears that the libspotify page is once again no longer able to generate application keys.  When trying, either via Firefox or Internet Explorer, the page reports that "There was an error generating your application key".  Is the site down again, or am I doing something wrong?  I've never used that page before.

Comment: Per the SpotifyPlatform Twitter account, the service is having issues.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about the Quality-of-service of spotify. Only questions about the spotify api are on-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Earlier today, the SpotifyPlatform Twitter account reported that the service is having issues.  However, they must either be working on it or have finished doing so as a key request I just put in worked properly.

Comment: Since the issue was temporary and since it's completely offtopic to the Stack Overflow, please remove the question or at the very least mark it as "solved/accepted", and the others will close it as "offtopic" in some time.